# Decoupling a definition of an interface from its implementation

Tags: oop, go, interface

During the course of Tour of Go, the following extract is presented but I couldn't make much meaning of it (guess I'm lacking in OOP knowledge).

> An interface in Go is defined as a set of method signatures. In Go interfaces are implicit. So there is no need to define on a given type that it implements a certain interface. The advantage of this is that the definition of an interface is decoupled from its implementation which could then appear in any package without prearrangement.

How is `decoupling a definition of an interface from its implementation` advantageous? My initial thought is that this approach greatly reduces the 'rigidity' (aka significance) of interfaces.. is it just syntactic-sugar and things actually "work as normal" under the hood?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: it's a tough question actually. It depends on point of view. Implicit implementation may be great for someone and bad for another one. There is no dichotomy here.

Comment: @felipsmartins Agreed. I'm used to more rigid interfaces so this approach by Golang got me a bit concerned. Do you know of any "design workaround" to bring Golang interfaces a little closer to what we have in, say, PHP or Java?

Comment: Do not try to make Go more like PHP or Java. It will only cause more frustration and make your code more difficult to understand by other Go developers. Work *with* Go, not *against* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "duck typing", and it allows interfaces to be defined where they are needed, instead of as part of the data type itself. Consider the following type:

```
type X struct {...}

func (X) f()
func (X) g()
func (X) h()
```

The type `X` has three methods, `f()`, `g()`, `h()`. If you have a data structure or function that needs to call a `f()` method, you can define an interface:

```
type FIntf interface {
   f()
}
```

and now `X` implements that interface. You can pass instances of `X` wherever `FIntf` is needed.

If, in another module you need `g()` and `h()`, you can define an interface there:

```
type GIntf interface {
  g()
  h()
```

and now `X` implements `GIntf`.

This is especially useful if you have a third-party library that doesn't implement the interfaces you need. You can simply define an interface where you use it, and use the third-party types with the correct method set implement your interface.

The main advantage of this method is that you can still emulate the traditional notion of interfaces where you define an interface and a concrete implementation of it. On top of that, you have the flexibility to define different interfaces as you need them without modifying the implementation. In a language like Java, if you have a function that gets a certain interface and if your object doesn't, you have to write an adapter even though the method set exists on the original type. In Go, you don't need to do that.

Duck typing also allows for type-safety when it comes to calling methods. For instance, if you have a function that has to call method `x()` and `y()` of one of its arguments, define an interface containing `x()` and `y()`, and use a type assertion to validate the argument implements those two methods.

Comment: Golang seems really simple and practical. I still have some concerns about how DDD and even some design patterns would turn out to be in the Golang space, but your answer already clarifies a ton. Thanks!

Comment: The key is to change the way you approach problems instead of trying to emulate features you find in other languages in go. In my experience, after writing tons of Java code, the emphasis shift from "writeable" to "readable" is much more important that strict adherence to design patterns.

Comment: It may be worth to point out that duck-typing is often used to describe dynamic type systems such as Python's while Go is statically typed.